# Why is $\mathbb{R}^1$ different than Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^1$? Roger Penrose road to reality

Tags: spacetime, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

In Roger's book, the following is stated: (I'm paraphrasing because my book is in spanish)

"We consider time as part of a space, namely $\mathbb{E}^1$, instead of it just being a copy of the line $\mathbb{R}$. This is because $\mathbb{R}^1$ has the privileged element 0 which would represent the origin of time"

I don't get why this would be true, because, according to what I know, $\mathbb{E}^1$ also would have its zero.

He goes on and talks about how theres also no origin for space in $\mathbb{E}$. But I'm also confused about this.

I understand the idea, of course, what I don't get is how you can mathematically model a space with no origin?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space

Comment: Is $\mathbb{E}$ an affine space then?

Comment: Yes. Going by name, it's probably supposed to be an [Euclidean space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space), which is an affine space with some additional structure, in particular angles (not terribly useful in the 1-dimensional case) and distances and corresponding motions (rotations and translations)

Comment: Hmm. I'm having trouble interpreting how one would define a position vector in an affine space. How can you refer to a point (t,$\mathbf{x}$)? Is this a problem?

Comment: You can use a vector space to represent an affine space - you just have to remember that you're not allowed to do addition or scalar multiplication. Consider dates: What's the result of adding March 13th to December 4th? That's nonsense. However, what you can do is add a duration to a date, which would be what is called 'displacement vector' in general. General relativity (or analytical mechanics) goes even farther than that: In curved spaces, finite displacements generally do not make sense, and you have to stick with infinitesimal ones (tangent vectors)

Comment: @Christoph: that should be an answer. It's an important point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that $\mathbb E^n$ denotes [Euclidean space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space). In addition to having geometric structure (angles and distances) and motions (rotations, translations, reflections) - not all of it terribly useful in the 1-dimensional case - it is an [affine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space).

Affine spaces have no notion of distinguished origin or zero point. We can use a vector space like $\mathbb R^n$ to represent an affine space, but we have to be aware that not all operations defined on a vector space are allowed in the affine case. In particular, addition and scalar multiplication make no sense in affine spaces, whereas substraction still does, but will result in a displacement vector that is not part of the affine space itself, but an associated vector space.

As an example, consider dates: What's the result of adding March 13th to December 4th? That's nonsense. However, you can ask how many days lie between two dates, and you can add such a duration to a date and get a well-defined result. Displacing a point by a vector is fine, but adding two points is not.

Note that this goes even further in general relativity (and analytical mechanics): In curved spaces or spaces without the necessary structure, there might not be a coordinate-independent notion of finite displacement. The best we can do are infinitesimal displacements (tangent vectors) tied to specific points of the base space. It's probably a good idea not to think of these in terms of displacements at all, but velocities, even if we sometimes do have things like the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map) that blur that distinction.

Comment: When Roger talks about points in this space like (t,$\mathbf{x}$) has he made use of an arbitrarily defined origin? Or what exactly does a position vector of this sort mean here?

Comment: @David: exactly; after choice of origin (as well as a set of basis vectors), $\mathbb R^n$ can be used to label the points of the abstract affine space